# How to get a text field with each radio input in cck

Tags: entities

I want to have a text field input in front of every radio input so, that when a user selects a radio input the appropreate textfield will appear infront of every radio input in node/add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the [Double field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module

> Double field is a small module written to provide extensions to Drupal's core Fields. By this module you can split your fields up into two separate parts.
>
> For the moment it includes the following sub-widget types:
>
> - Textfield
> - Select list
> - Single checkbox
> - Textarea
>
> Consequently, in all there are 4 x 4 = 16 widget types.

You can also achieve that using [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module.

> This module Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.

But this module requires the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module. Also note that this field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too.

Comment: Thanxs for looking into it i will check it..

Comment: @harsh Did you try this module?

Comment: I tried it but it gives a checkbox what i want is a radio button